# Check new lines before format element scanf

Tags: c, stdio

So, I want to read some input in two integer variables with `fscanf`, the input must be

`INTEGER` `ONE SPACE` `INTEGER` `\n`

So for example a file could be like that:

`235 190\n`

And what I want to do is checking if there is any new line before the first integer or the second, then throw an exception if that's the case:

So basically what you do with `fscanf` for that case would be just to do like:

```
FILE *somefile;
[...]
int w, h;
if (fscanf(somefile, "%d%d") == EOF)
    return (1);
```

But this method does not provide checking if there is a new line between the integers

(for example if there is `INTEGER` `NEW_LINE` `INTEGER` it will still read the second)

as it skips all spaces before seeing a digit, so what I managed to do is more close but still wrong:

```
FILE *somefile;
int w, h;
char check[2];
if (fscanf(somefile, "%d%c%d%c", &w, check, &h, check + 1) == EOF)
    return (-1);
if (check[0] != ' ' || check[1] != '\n')
    return (-1);
```

So after I did that I realized that the `%c` before the `%d` just reads one character, so if there is a space then a new line between the two, it will continue reading the file wrongly and won't detect an error.
Now I wonder if there is a way to skip all spaces like when using `" %c"`, while knowing if we skipped a `\n`. Thanks for your help.

PS: I know we can use `fgets` and `strtol` but it would be too easy, in this project I can only use `fscanf` to parse the file.

Comment: [Read a whole line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) first. Then use `sscanf` to parse the line, and check that [`sscanf` returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) `2`.

Comment: Since `fscanf()` does not care about newlines etc, you can't use it.  You'll need to use [`fgets()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or 
POSIX [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read the line, and then `sscanf()` to check the formatting.

Comment: `scanf` happily discards all whitespace to match a `%d`, so it will not be useful to you.

Comment: If you can only use `fscanf()`, you are being pushed into a path of misery.  For the required input format, `fscanf()` is mostly the wrong tool for the right job.  You can use it, but you're going to have to work very hard, calling it multiple times, and you'll probably need to use `ungetc()` as part of the processing.  The workload is going to be gruesome!  See William Pursell's answer, and replace each call to `getchar()` with a call to `fscanf()` to read a character plus a test to see that you got the right character (plus the `ungetc()` to put it back when necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is a way to skip all spaces

> I can only use fscanf to parse the file.

Let us assume `ungetc()` is not allowed - which makes things harder.

---

`"%d"` happily consumes all (0 or more) leading white-spaces including `'\n'` without notice.

Use `fscanf("%[...]")` to find leading white-spaces first.  The [usual suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqFVLAKaEWs) are `" \t\n\r\f\v"`.

```
// Consume leading whitespaces 
// Return
// 1: \n or EOF found
// 0: not found
int EatLeadingWS(FILE *f) {
  int count;
  char space[2];
  while ((count = fscanf("%1[ \t\n\r\f\v]", space)) == 1) {
    if (space[0] == '\n') return 1;
  }
  return count == EOF;
}
```

Alternative: use `"%c"` and `isspace()`, but then we need a way to put non white-spaces back.

Then look for white-spaces before `"%d"`

```
int some_int;
if (EatLeadingWS(f) == 0) {
  int count;
  if ((count = fscanf("%d", &some_int)) == 1) { 
    printf("int %d found before a \\n\n", some_int);
  }
}
```

---

Another alternative is to use `char buf[100]; fscanf("%99[^\n]", buf)` to read most of the line and then parse the string with `sscanf(buf, "%d%1[ ]%d" ....`

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late answer. Just one question: why do you use an array of 2 for `int space[2]` instead of just `int space` as you only read one character?

Comment: @Fayeure With `fscanf("%1[ \t\n\r\f\v]", space)`, code does indeed _read_ up to 1 character.  Yet `"%[...]"` saves that character and _appends_ a _null character_.  Thus 2 needed in (corrected) `char space[2];`

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` happily discards leading whitespace to match a `%d` conversion specifier, which makes this slightly difficult to do.  But you can certainly use `fgetc` (or `getchar`) to validate a character and then push it back onto the stream for `scanf` to consume.  Something like:

```
$ cat a.c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
        int c;
        int d[2];
        c = getchar();
        if( 0
                ||!( c == '+' || c == '-' || isdigit(c))
                || ( c != ungetc(c, stdin) )
                || ( scanf("%d", d) != 1 )
                || ( getchar() != ' ' )
                || ( (c = getchar()) == EOF )
                ||!( c == '+' || c == '-' || isdigit(c))
                || ( c != ungetc(c, stdin) )
                || ( scanf("%d", d + 1) != 1 )
                || ( getchar() != '\n' )
        ){
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid input!\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("Read %d %d\n", d[0], d[1]);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
$ gcc a.c
$ printf '5 28\n' | ./a.out
Read 5 28
$ printf '5  28\n' | ./a.out
invalid input!
$ printf ' 5 28\n' | ./a.out
invalid input!
$ printf ' 5 28' | ./a.out
invalid input!
```

Comment: If the teacher of the OP is wanting a solution similar to this, it's a definite proof that the teacher is a sadistic as... Well, not a very nice person.